# WebExtensions -- WebRequest event not triggering successfully despite matching network requests

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an extension with WebExtensions and have run into a problem with WebRequest events. I am attempting to intercept the response to the request that the Facebook.com newsfeed sends to load more posts, which occurs through the URL `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/LitestandTailLoadPagelet?dpr=*` (where `*` is a whole mess of identifiers). This request shows up in the devtools:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23peh.png).

Here's the relevant manifest bits:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "*://facebook.com/*",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://facebook.com/", "*://facebook.com/groups/?*"],
        "js": ["/content-script.js"],
        "css": ["/css/styles.css"]
    }]
}
```

In background.js, I have the following event listener at the very top of the file (not that order should matter here):

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    details => { console.log("event"); }, 
    { urls: ["https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/LitestandTailLoadPagelet?dpr=*"] }, 
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

However, making the request (even re-sending the one pictured above with the same url) doesn't trigger the console.log or even a breakpoint set on the event through devtools. The page loads no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: All documentation about "Match Patterns" refer to scheme, host and path - nothing suggests you can match the "search" portion of the URL (the part after ?) ... of course, nothing suggests you can't either so my comment so far is pretty useless :p - as a test, remove `?dpr=*` in the urls just to see if that gets triggered

Comment: Good idea, but the match patterns work with any text and wildcards that include *. I tried it anyways, same result -- no matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to intercept requests to `www.facebook.com` but you don't have a host permission for that domain (you do have `facebook.com` but that's a different domain)